# Transforming bipartite graph data to one-mode with MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, r, gephi

I have been trying to convert a really big dataset, which is a bipartite network, into a weighed one-mode network, so I can make a visual presentation of it with Gephi. There is a plugin in Gephi for this, but the program crashes when I run it because the dataset is too big. I have also tried a little with R, but I have no experience with it, so I thought I would explore the possibilities with what I already have some experience.

My question: Can this be done with a MySQL query, and will it be efficient?

My data is stored on a MySQL database, and currently looks like this:

```
A | 1
A | 2
A | 3
B | 1
B | 2
C | 2
C | 3
```

And what I need is like this, where the 3rd column is the weight of how many they have in common.

```
A | B | 2
A | C | 2
B | C | 1
```

I am not too great with MySQL queries, but I thought that if I could somehow make a query to transform the data to look like this:

```
A | 1 | B
A | 2 | B
A | 2 | C
A | 3 | C
B | 2 | C
```

I would then be able to make a count on the data to get the weight.

I am not only looking for help with how to make a query for this, but also if it would be an effecient way of transforming the data.

I hope you can help and if I need to elaborate on something please let me know.

Comment: You should quantify "really big dataset".

Comment: I currently have 11 million rows in the first table which would grow quite a lot over time, when I figure how to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self join and an aggregation:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col1, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.col2 = t2.col2
group by t1.col1, t2.col1;
```

This will not be really efficient, but it is probably as efficient as you are going to get with the tools you have on hand.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for taking your time to make a response.

I can't make it work. It's probably because I dont understand it. I only have one table that looks like the first example in my post, so I'm a bit confused about what t1 and t2 is. Also I can't quite figure what the "t" is in lines 2 and 3.

Comment: Actually I think I got it, t is the existing table, right? At least it is running now, so I'll get back when I see the result :)

Comment: @M.Kahlen . . . Yes, `t` is the existing table, which you do not name in the question.

Comment: Alright. I have another question if you don't mind. It has been running for almost 15 hours now and I can see on the tasklist, that mysqld is using a fair amount of CPU (41%) but very little memory (618MB) and I have 32GB installed. So I wondered if there are some settings in MySQL that would allow it to use more resources and run faster?

Comment: @M.Kahlen . . . An index on `t(col2, col1)` would help performance.  However, it might be tricky if there are values of `col2` with lots and lots of rows.

Comment: The two columns are the primary key so all rows are unique and the primary key is indexed as far as i can see. Should I add an index to the columns separately?

Comment: @M.Kahlen . . . No, but a composite index might help.